# Не устанавливаеться утилита make, в debian 9

Tags: linux, debian

Воспользоваться командой

```
apt-get install make
```

Он мне выдал такой результат

```
root@R2CPU:/# apt-get install make
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
  make-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  make
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 290 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1164 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Err:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main armhf make armhf 4.1-9.1
  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/m/make-dfsg/make_4.1-9.1_armhf.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Я так и не понял почему компьютер не смог связаться с репозиторием , возможно его стоит сначало настроить ?? 
Возможно это связанно с интернетом ??

Я просто интернетовский провод вставил

```
root@R2CPU:/# fec 2188000.ethernet eth0: Link is Up - 100Mbps/Full - flow control off
```

посмотрел настройки репозитория `/etc/resolv.conf` как по мне всё **ОК**

```
root@R2CPU:/etc# more resolv.conf
nameserver 192.168.1.250
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы зачем-то пишете в интерпретатор командной строки всякий хлам без разбору.

Comment: `sudo rm -f /etc/resolv.conf && echo nameserver 8.8.8.8 | sudo tee /etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: «Почему-то не сработала команда auto ?» — потому что такой команды никогда ни в каком линуксе не существовало.

Comment: @andreymal   [а тут пишут](https://losst.ru/nastrojka-seti-debian-9) что есть. Я не особо знаю, что делаю по этому, так много хлама в командной строке.

Comment: Нет там ничего такого. Там записывают строчку «auto eth0» в файл с настройками, а не команду выполняют. То же самое с nameserver — такой команды нет и никогда не существовало, это строчка в файле

Comment: «Я не особо знаю, что делаю» — в таком случае вам следует прочитать любой учебник по основам линукса и базовым юниксовым командам, прежде чем делать что-либо ещё.

Comment: @andreymal  у меня только терминал есть. рабочего стола нету, а как и что сделать я не понимаю ибо мне кажется что "операционка" у меня сильно обрезанная .

Comment: Больше ничего, кроме как читать учебники по основам линукса, я посоветовать не могу. Полноценная операционка не требует существования рабочего стола и вообще графического интерфейса — можно целиком и полностью полноценно работать в терминале (даже играть в игры и задавать вопросы на Stack Overflow тоже можно через терминал, было бы желание)

Comment: @andreymal читал (Керриск М. - Linux API. Исчерпывающее руководство), вообще не очём. Просто не возможно работать, да и ответа как установить утилиту `make` увы нету.

Comment: Так вам не нужно Linux API, вам нужны основы работы с терминалом

Comment: @andreymal так ведь проблема не в терминале , а в том что я не могу установить утилиту `make`

Comment: Так ведь проблема в том, что вы даже не смогли отредактировать файл, который нужно отредактировать по [показанной вами инструкции](https://losst.ru/nastrojka-seti-debian-9)

Comment: Ну а вообще команду, которая (временно) исправляет указанную ошибку, я уже написал во втором комментарии

Comment: @andreymal , спасибо за команду :3 , не подскажете хорошую книжку по работе в терминале линух , спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С начала воспользовался командой `ip addr flush dev eth0`
 следующая команда `dhclient` 
следующая команда `ping www.ru` для проверки подключения можно хоть `ping picabu.ru`

Я воспользовался этими командами и они сработали. Хотя честно хочу сказать суть команды ip addr flush dev eth0

- ip addr показывает мой айпи (команду отображения частного IP-адреса)
- flush - торрент-клиент в линуксе ????
- dev - обозначение фаловой системмы.
- eth0 - инициализированное соединение интернет соединения.

По сути команда выполняет привязку айпи адреса этого компьютера с инициализированным интернет соединением через торрент-клиент (по сути "торент-клиент" встроенная в линукс, утилита).

Comment: Разъяснение сути команды бред конечно https://ss64.com/bash/ip-address-show.html , да и команда выполняет не привязку, а наоборот отвязку

Comment: @andreymal ктож мешает отредактировать  тире поправить ??? Просто я не хакер , я так газорежчик :3